# Inequality on conditional variance of a vector

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, expectation

I have a random vector $X$ and an event $\mathcal{E}$ such that $\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{E}) = p$. I am trying to show the following inequality :
\begin{equation}
p\mathbb{E}[\|X - \mathbb E [X \vert \mathcal E]\|^2\vert \mathcal E] \leq \mathbb E \|X - \mathbb E [X] \|^2
\end{equation}

I have been trying to use the properties of the conditional variance for this but I got confused over how to generalize the properties from the variance of a real random variable to that of random vector.

I am not sure the $p$ factor on the LHS is necessary. Can someone please give me a hand ?

Comment: $||X-\mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal{E}]||^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\mathbb{E}[X_i|\mathcal{E}])^2$, so by linearity of (conditional) expectation if you know the analogue of the result for real random variables, you can deduce it for random vectors.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question based on Julius' comment. Let $X_i$ be one of the coordinates, using the inequality given in [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2119663/expected-conditional-variance-inequality) for $X_i = y$, without conditioning on x and with $z = \mathbb{1}(\mathcal E)$ we get
\begin{equation}
Var(X_i) \geq \mathbb E [Var(X_i \vert \mathbb 1 (\mathcal E))] = p Var(X_i\vert \mathbb 1 (\mathcal E) = 1) + (1-p)Var(X_i\vert \mathbb 1 (\mathcal E) = 0)
\end{equation}
where $Var(Z\vert U) = \mathbb E [(Z - \mathbb E [Z \vert U])^2\vert U]$. It follows that $p Var(X_i\vert \mathbb 1 (\mathcal E) = 1) \leq Var(X_i)$ which is the inequality I wanted to show in the scalar case. It only remains to use Julius' comment to conclude.
Thanks Julius